# Getting [[null]] in nested coordinates array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a mongoose schema like this:

```
l:{
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: { type: Array }
}
```

and I'm looking for all Points and Polygons in the DB to get their coordinates but the problem comes with the Polygons, Example result:

```
_id: n26608798 -> Coordinates: [-4.4991265,36.6750467]
_id: n1753741872 -> Coordinates: [-4.498763,36.6717949]
_id: w93748323 -> Coordinates: [[null]]
```

The last result is a Polygon and `[[null]]`should be something like this:

`[
    [
        [-4.4948252,36.6770003],
        [-4.4948708,36.6770321],
        [-4.4945418,36.6773356],
        [-4.4944965,36.6773035],
        [-4.4947042,36.6771119],
        [-4.4947491,36.6770705],
        [-4.4948252,36.6770003]
    ]
]`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
The problem was an `eval()` I was using above :/